# Не правильно возвращает Json

Tags: php, json

Возвращаю Json таки образом.

```
json_encode($data['action'])
```

Но он почему то не возвращает открывающий тег `<p>` в поле `discription` и `text`.

Вот возврат json

```
{"action":[{"id":"2","title":"\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21162","date":"2015-11-16 17:25:07","discription":"
Action action<\/p>\n","text":"

Action action<\/span><\/p>\n","img":""},{"id":"1","title":"\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161","date":"2015-11-16 17:24:50","discription":"

\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161<\/p>\n","text":"

\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161  \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161 \u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u21161<\/p>\n","img":"cce070f46c340d125936f1828b7e7533.jpg"}]}
```

Точно возвращает вместе с открывающимся тегом

Но в json ответе его нет.

[Вот пример](http://rp.kamnedsoft.kz/api/get_action)

Сверху можно посмотреть что я получаю из базы с тегом `<p>` а ниже json без этого тега. Почему?

Comment: оформите вопрос правильно - данные из которых формируете json внесите в теги кода, а не делайте ссылку на постороннюю страницу, тем более без форматирования кода.

Comment: После форматирования вопрос все равно не понятен. По ссылке идет `print_r($data['action']);`?

Comment: @MichaelPak Сначала идет print_r а ниже Json

Comment: Дебагинг возврата строк HTML путем простого вывода в браузер - не самая лучшая идея. Попробуйте вывести  в консоль. Или используйте htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
json_encode($data['action'], JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Более подробно в [мануале PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php).